# referring a resource yaml from another directory in kustomization

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kustomize

I have a resource yaml file in a folder structure given below

> base
>
> ---- first.yaml
>
> main
>
> ---- kustomization.yaml

In kustomization.yaml I am referring the first.yaml as

> resources:
>
> - ../base/first.yaml

But I am getting an error when i do apply of kubectl apply -f kustomizatio.yaml

```
accumulating resources: accumulating resources from '../base/first.yaml': security; file '../base/first.yaml' is not in or below '../base'
```

How can i call the first.yaml resource from the folder base to the kustomization in main folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kustomize cannot refer to individual resources in parent directories, it can only refer to resources in current or child directories, but it can refer to other Kustomize directories.

The following would be a valid configuration for what you have:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   └── resource.yaml
│   └── stuff
│       ├── first.yaml
│       └── kustomization.yaml
└── cluster
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

Contents of `base/main/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - resource.yaml
```

Contents of `base/stuff/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - first.yaml
```

Contents of `cluster/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
 - ../base/main
 - ../base/stuff
```

Comment: TL;DR; overlay `kustomization.yaml` section for `resources:` contains parent dir of base `kustomization.yaml`, for people who skim instead of read everything carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Run `kustomize build` from one folder down, `kustomize build ./main`. You aren't allowed to `..` up past where kustomize started from, just to be safe.